# Visual Paradigm set attribute to final in class diagram

Tags: class-diagram

Hello I want to draw a class diagram with Visual Paradigm and I have to set my attributes to "final".

I tried the following Syntax: `-final id : UUID`

When I generate a getter it looks like this: `+getFinal id() : UUID`

I expected `+getId() : UUID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML does not specify what 'final' means. That is a Java keyword.

Place a readOnly modifier on your property.

In order for that to show up in the diagram, you must *right click the diagram*, go *Presentation Options*,  go *Attribute Display Options* and tick *Show Property Modifiers.*
[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you very much! A little addition to your answer: to set an attribute to read only: right click attribute > Open Specification... > check Read only checkbox. > Ok.